# Trying to clean disk space, but can't remove packages

Tags: apt, disk-usage, 21.04

On my Ubuntu server, the root has taken up all the available disk space and I can't expand the partition. I'm trying to remove some old packages to free up some space but I can't because I don't have enough disk space to store the package lists. Anyone know how I can clear some space so I can uninstall packages? Thanks!

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# apt-get remove samba
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick will be to try to release a minimum of space, so that `apt-get` can work again.

See here to [find out what is taking the place](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262654/whats-filling-up-my-root-directory).

If there are user data, move that out first. If not, then you could [empty the log files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do).

That will allow `apt` to work. Run `sudo apt clean` to remove downloaded `.deb` files, `sudo apt autoremove` to automatically remove packages that are not needed. If `sudo apt autoremove` did not remove all old kernels, you may want to [remove them manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu).

It is important to diagnose why your / would have filled. If the cause is not removed, you will quickly hit the problem again.

Comment: Thank you, it was actually some pm2 logs taking up 8Gb on my 16Gb SD card!